# how can I filter an array of objects when two object are the same?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects like this:

```
[
  {
    category: 'ELECTRONICS',
    sub_category: 'CONSOLE'
  },
  {
    category: 'ELECTRONICS',
    sub_category: 'CONSOLE'
  },
  {
    category: 'ELECTRONICS',
    sub_category: 'TV'
  }
]
```

Now I want to filter when category and sub_category same.

How can I do it ?

Comment: What did you try??

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: What's your end goal? The category and subcategory are never the same in any given object in this array.

Answer (score 0):

A simple comparison of the two string will do the trick.

```js
const data = [
  {
    category: "ELECTRONICS",
    sub_category: "CONSOLE"
  },
  {
    category: "ELECTRONICS",
    sub_category: "CONSOLE"
  },
  {
    category: "ELECTRONICS",
    sub_category: "TV"
  }
];

const result = data.filter(e => e.category === e.sub_category);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Not correct, in the array should only be electronics and tv object, because both are not same

Comment: What exactly is the criterium to remove an element?

Answer (score -1):

```js
const data = [
  {
    category: 'ELECTRONICS',
    sub_category: 'CONSOLE'
  },
  {
    category: 'ELECTRONICS',
    sub_category: 'CONSOLE'
  },
  {
    category: 'ELECTRONICS',
    sub_category: 'TV'
  }
]

const filter = data.filter(i => i.category == "ELECTRONICS" && i.sub_category == "TV")

console.log(filter)
```

Comment: Please take a look at [*How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: This does not answers OP's question.